# Read/Write Data in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: selenium, data-driven-tests

I am not using MS office in my local machine. So I am using Google Docs.

Now I need to create a script that fetches the data from google spreadsheet in Selenium.

I want to fetch the data[Read/Write] from the Google spreadsheet using selenium web-driver.

Is anyone have an idea about how to do it?

**Technologies:**
Selenium Web-Driver
JAVA
TestNG
Eclipse IDE

Comment: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/read-data-from-google-spreadsheet-using-api

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you open public spreadsheet just as example and show code that tries to change it ??

Comment: @AdiOhana: Thank You for your input. It's a Maven project but I need to create a script in TestNg.

Comment: @JalpeshPatel-QALead the SO post I mentioned is using TestNG and Selenium

Comment: @cruisepandey: So far I had tried to create a Credentials in Google APIs after enabling the Spreadsheet API. But I do not have any idea of how to read data from the Google Spreadsheet. Even though I had tried with multiple codes that I have found from Google.

Comment: Please update your question with tried code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Google Sheets right now, but I'm guessing it would look something like this.

```
pip install gspread oauth2client
```

Then...

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

Or, get a list of lists:

```
sheet.get_all_values()
```

Finally, you could just pull the data from a single row, column, or cell:

```
sheet.row_values(1)

sheet.col_values(1)

sheet.cell(1, 1).value
```

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2

Comment: Thank You so much for your effort and help. I have gone through with your comment and provided links But its a Python code. So I do not clearly convert in the selenium-java.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry.  I found this when I did a search on 'Python' or 'Selenium'.  I just read through your question really quickly.  I thought you were looking for a Python/Selenium solution, not Java.  I know literally nothing about Java.  Hopefully someone comes along with a workable solution sometime soon.